# Config setting to open phpMyAdmin in default browser?

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-vista, phpmyadmin, wamp

Is it possible to configure phpMyAdmin to open with the default browser?  I searched in the .ini files in case there might be some string related to 'browser' or 'mozilla' etc, but couldn't find anything.  Basically what's happening is it keeps looking for Firefox to open with, presumably because this was the default at the time I installed/upgraded.
I have WAMP 2.0 on Vista.

Comment: It's not phpMyAdmin that's trying to open Firefox, it's your Vista config having Firefox as the app associated with whatever you're trying to open (i.e. .html or .php files or whatever).  This is off-topic for SF.

Comment: All other apps with links to browser files open with the system's default browser.  It's just phpMyAdmin that doesn't.  Since it's related to Apache, this seemed like the correct forum :/

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to create a shortcut on the desktop ( or wherever else ) for the location type the address of your phpMyAdmin page.

That should work perfectly.

[right-click]->
 [New]->
  [Shortcut]

for location, type your phpMyAdminAddress

click [Next]

Enter a name for your shortcut.

**EDIT**
Your problem may be a file association error.  Hold right click while opening the file then go to "open with".  Choose (or find) whatever browser you want to open it from this dialog.

However, you probably should be using the URL on your server to access the phpMyAdmin page, not a local copy.

Comment: I always appreciate a -1 when trying to actually help someone.  Way to be constructive on ServerFault.

Comment: The question is off-topic (it's not related to the material in the FAQ), and I felt the answer you gave didn't address the question as stated, I voted (with my own reputation being reduced) appropriately.  If people disagree with me, then the -1 will be outvoted by them (at no cost to their own rep).